# Arch Linux: How to set a key or key binding to execute a command?

Tags: linux, command-line, arch-linux, hotkeys

In Arch Linux, how do I set some key binding (let's say Alt + <) to execute a particular command? I know you could use Xmodmap to bind one key to another, but I want to be able to run a particular command when the key or keybinding is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly all desktop environments (or standalone window managers) have their own features for creating custom key bindings. For example, in GNOME, open "Settings → Keyboard → View and Customize Shortcuts → Custom Shortcuts". Similarly i3 and Sway have the `bindsym` configuration statement.

If the window manager has no such feature, the `sxhkd` or `xbindkey` daemons can be used in X11.

Answer (score 0):

In the desktop environment KDE Plasma, go to "Custom Shortcuts" (System Settings > Workspace > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts) to add keys.

For example, to set up en dash: hit Edit > New Group. Right click on the new group and go to New > Global Shortcut > Send Keyboard Input. Go to the "Trigger" tab, and type in your command (e.g. Alt + -). Go to the "Action" tab, and write in "Ctrl+Shift+U:2:0:1:3:Enter" (using the unicode "U+2013" to get the en dash). Then tick the box next to the new group / new command you just created to enable that command and hit "Apply". Now, if you hit "Alt+-", it will return "–".

Similarly, instead of "Send Keyboard Input", you can select New > Global Shortcut > Command/URL. Set the "Trigger", then on the "Action" tab, you can type in a location of a command to run.